# why tomcat7 is using so much RAM?

Tags: java, tomcat7, memory-leak

My Server has only .5GB free memory out of 65GB.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         64375      63788        587          0         70      11503
-/+ buffers/cache:      52213      12161
Swap:        67583       6923      60660
```

Tomcat is using around 22GB memory.

```
root     19915  2.9 36.4 42514364 24036804 ?   Sl   Jun21 433:25 /usr/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java 
   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/conf/logging.properties 
   -server -Xms2048m -Xmx22528m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
   -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:NewSize=512m -Xnoclassgc
   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 
   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/endorsed 
   -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:
              /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
   -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11 
   -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11 
   -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.11/temp 
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Other applications are using a small amount of memory.
I don't understand what is happening. If there is a memory leak in tomcat then how to confirm it and fix that.

Answer (score 4):

Stop staring at the column `free`: [Linux ate your RAM](https://www.linuxatemyram.com) for *disk caching* (`cached 11503`).  As long as `cached` is high and `swap used` is low, you are not out of memory.

Tomcat have had issues with memory leaks - usually not from its own codebase but from poorly written applications. It's not necessarily the case here. Tomcat 7 has [MemoryLeakProtection](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) you can use to investigate this further:

> Starting with tomcat 6.0.25, the manager webapp has a new "Find Leaks"
>   button. When triggered, it displays a list of webapps (their context
>   path) that have been stopped (this includes undeployed and redeployed
>   ones) but whose classloader failed to be GCed.
>
> If a leaking webapp is redeployed several times, it will appear as
>   many times as it actually leaked.

Answer (score 4):

Your Tomcat is using 22GB of memory because your -Xmx (JVM Heap Size) value is absolutely massive.

If possible, you should start by reducing this value to 2048, 4096 or 8192, depending on your application memory requirements and see what the sweet spot is.

Comment: Nicely spotted, @Miuku! I'll add some line breaks to the question for readability.

Comment: Also, it's not necessarily wrong to use 22GB out of 64GB if the main use for this server is to run this application. If the memory needs to be more evenly distributed between applications, then decreasing `-Xmx` is the solution.